# Text.strip() Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Estou tentando fazer um código que extraia algumas informações de uma página. O Arquivo possui o seguinte formato:

```
<tr class="impar">
    <td class="id">
        <a href="/judge/en/runs/code/5046623">5046623</a>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="tiny">
        <a href="/judge/en/problems/view/2173">2173</a>
    </td>
    <td class="wide">
        <a href="/judge/en/problems/view/2173">Slush Fund</a>
    </td>
    <td class="semi-wide answer a-1">
        <a href="/judge/en/runs/code/5046623">Accepted</a>
    </td>
    <td class="center">C++</td>
    <td class="tiny">0.084</td>
    <td class="center">8/27/16, 10:10:39 PM</td>
</tr>
```

Implementei o seguinte código em Python para extrair as informações: id = 2173, name = Slush Fund, language: C++. Entretanto eu recebo o seguinte erro:

```
File "C:/Users/diego/Desktop/main.py", line 35, in extractProblems
 "language": td[4].text.strip()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Meu código:

```
def extractProblems(self, soup, problems):
    itens = soup.find_all('table')[0].find_all('tbody')[0].find_all('tr')
    for tr in itens:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        if len(td) != 8:
            return 
        else:                
            problems[td[1].find('a').text.strip()] = {
                "id_code": td[2].find('a').text.strip(),
                "name": td[3].find('a').text.strip(),
                "language": td[4].text.strip()
            }
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: O mais provável é que algum dos teus `td[i].find('a')` não esteja achando nada, aí `td[i].find('a')` seria `None`. E como o erro aponta, `None` não tem um atributo chamado `text`.

Comment: Resolveu o problema?

Answer (score 0):

Este é o seu `td[1]`, onde você aplica o `td[1].find('a').text.strip()` para obter o código e gerar o índice para o dicionário `problems`:

```
<td>
</td>
```

Ou seja, não tem nada. Está vazio e vai dar erro quando você procurar a tag `<a>` e o `text` dela. O dado que você quer está em `td[0]`:

```
<td class="id">
<a href="/judge/en/runs/code/5046623">5046623</a> </td>
<td>
```

Troque `td[1]` por `td[0]`:

```
problems[td[0].find('a').text.strip()] = {
    "id_code": td[2].find('a').text.strip(),
    "name": td[3].find('a').text.strip(),
    "language": td[4].text.strip()
}
```